# 2-way anova on unbalanced dataset

Tags: r, anova

Is `aov` appropriate for unbalanced datasets. According to help `...provides a wrapper to lm for fitting linear models to balanced or unbalanced experimental designs`. But later on it says `aov is designed for balanced designs, and the results can be hard to interpret without balance`.

How should I perform a 2-way anova on an unbalanced dataset in R?

I would like to reproduce the different results for type I and type III sum of squares of `SAS` output (when using `proc glm`). I remember we were using `type III sum of squares` for unbalanced datasets.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Speaking of type III sum of squares: http://rfortunes.posterous.com/you-must-realize-that-r-is-written-by-experts

Comment: I think type III SS get a bad rap from the R community. In terms of general applicability I find them more useful than type I SS, though less useful than type II. I tend to almost always use the Anova function in the car package over the base anova.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Function `anova` (or `summary.aov`) will give you the so called type I (or sequential) sum of squares. To get type III sum of squares, you can use the [Anova](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/car/html/Anova.html) function from library `car` with parameter `type="III"`. The difference between these two approaches in unbalanced datasets (and also sample R code to produce both tables) is presented in detail [here](http://sites.psu.edu/stat461psbsp2013/wp-content/uploads/sites/1906/2013/03/InteractionsAndTypesOfSS.pdf).

Comment: Thank you very much. This paper seems to be very helpful and informative.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the Zahn paper. I hadn't seen it before.

Comment: @~unutbu: In the appendix :-)

Comment: Great explanation! really helpful!!